# Javascript changing to pointer-event CSS property of an element

Tags: javascript, css

I am using javascript and I need to change the style: pointer-events:none to pointer-events:auto and vice versa. How can I do this?

Comment: I normally supply much more info, but I think this is simply a question with a very basic subject and answer

Comment: Which bit are you having difficulty with? `element.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'` should suffice?

Comment: Ah that was my problem, I did not know the javascript property for pointer-events. I could have used z-index as well, but that would have been more of a hack

Comment: generally if the css property has a hyphen, the js equivalent is camelCase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery you can use:

```
$(function(){
    $('#yourElement').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that swaps the pointer event on an element.

in JavaScript

```
function swapPE(forme){
  if (forme.style.pointerEvents == "none") forme.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  else forme.style.pointerEvents = "none";
};
```

I usually activate this function by attaching the eventhandler

```
onClick(swapPE(this);)
```

to the element if directly activated.  If not I just call it with a reference to the element ID.

Previous to this I often wanted to change some appearance of the element as well so I used JavaScript to change the classname of the element where each classname included the relevant pointer-event statement.

If you want to use more then one pairing of pointer-events just send parameters.

```
onClick(swapPE(this, "auto", "none");)
or
onClick(swapPE(this, "all", "none");)

function swapPE(forme, ev1, ev2){
  if (forme.style.pointerEvents == ev1) forme.style.pointerEvents = ev2;
  else forme.style.pointerEvents = ev1;
};
```